# Backbone.Marionette: Add header to collection view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Using `Backbone.Marionette`, I would like to render a collection of items along with a header.

I'm aware that `Marionette.CollectionView` does not have a template, as it only renders `ItemView`s.

I'm currently using `Marionette.LayoutView`, but have to define an extra DOM element for the 'list' region.

Is there any other way to do this? Possibly without the extra DOM element?

Maybe I could change `open()` for this particular region?

---

**Current Result**:

```
<div class='collection'>
  <h3>Featured</h3>
  <div class="list"></div>
</div>
```

**Desired Result**:

```
<div class='collection'>
  <h3>List Name</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Render Code**:

```
var col = new LCollection([{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}]); // Defined earlier, not relevant here
var list = new ListView({collection: col});
var layout = new MyLayout({model: new Backbone.Model({name: "Featured"})});

app.featured.show(layout);
layout.list.show(list);
```

**Views**:

```
var ListItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: '#list-item',
  tagName: 'li'
});

var LessonListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  itemView: ListItemView
});

var MyLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: "list-layout",

  regions: {
    list: '.list'
  }
});
```

**Templates**:

```
<script type="text/template" id="list-item">
  <%= name %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="list-layout">
  <h3><%= name %></h3>
  <div class="list"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Why not a [CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md

Applied for you :

Templates

```
<script id="list-item" type="text/html">
  <%= name %>
</script>

<script id="list-layout" type="text/html">
    <div class='collection'>
        <h3><%= name %></h3>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
RowView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  template: "#list-item"
});

TableView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: RowView,
  // specify a jQuery selector to put the itemView instances in to
  itemViewContainer: "ul",
  template: "#list-layout"
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this before: `or for scenarios where a collection needs to be rendered within a wrapper template.` I'll try this out, and will let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: These days it's "childView" and "childViewContainer" instead of "itemView" and "itemViewContainer"

Comment: @CraigMyles I wish I had noticed your comment earlier - that would save me an hour or so :)

Comment: @MikhailBatcer I don't know what it should say now.  Toss an edit in there to have it up to date

Answer (score 1):

Marionette 3 doesn't use `CompositeView` any more, so if we want to get something like this:

```
<div class='collection'>
  <h3>List Name</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>FOO - BAR</li>
    <li>FOO - BAR</li>
    <li>FOO - BAR</li>
    ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

We have to use `CollectionView` & `View` with regions.

## 1 - Templates

We are going to define two templates, a first one that is the 'parent' and another one for each 'child' that the parent has.

#### parentTemplate.html

```
<div class='collection'>
    <h3>List Name</h3>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

#### childTemplate.html

```
<p>Item <%= value%></p>
```

## 2 - Backbone Model and Collection

Lets define a default model and its collection to fill the list.

```
const Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
const Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item
});
```

## 3 - Views

First, we have to create a `View` for our child representation, so:

```
import ItemViewTemplate from './childTemplate.html';    

const ItemChildView = Marionette.View.extend({
    template: _.template(ItemViewTemplate),
    className: 'item-child-view',
    tagName: 'li' // <-- The element where we will wrap our item template (it is not defined in the HTML file)
});
```

Second, we have to create a `CollectionView` that manages each child, so:

```
const ItemsCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'ul', // <-- The element where we will wrap our collection of items (it is already in the parent HTML file)
    childView: ItemChildView,
    className: 'items-collection-view'
});
```

Finally, we have to create the main `View`, that contains the parentTemplate.html and in this one we define the region where we will load the collection of elements, so:

```
import ItemsViewTemplate './parentTemplate.html';    

const ItemsView = Marionette.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'items-view',
    template: _.template(ItemsViewTemplate),
    regions: {
        body: {
            el: 'ul', // <-- This is the HTML tag where we want to load our CollectionView
            replaceElement: true // <-- With this option, we overwrite the HTML tag with our CollectionView tag
        }
    }
});
```

## 4- Rest of the Code

Now we create the instances needed to make this works:

```
const app = new Marionette.Application({
    region: '#main'
});

// Three simple Items
let item1 = new Item({value: 1});
let item2 = new Item({value: 2});
let item3 = new Item({value: 3});

// Put this Items into a Collection of Items
let items = new Items([item1, item2, item3]);

// Create the main View
let itemsView = new ItemsView();

app.showView(itemsView);

// Create the CollectionView for the Items
let itemsCollectionView = new ItemsCollectionView({
    collection: items
});

// Load the CollectionView of Items into the region that we specified in the main View
itemsView.showChildView('body', itemsCollectionView);

app.start();
```

## 5- Result

If we run this, we get:

```
<div class="collection">
    <h3>List Name</h3>
    <ul class="items-collection-view">
        <li class="item-child-view"><p>Item1</p></li>
        <li class="item-child-view"><p>Item2</p></li>
        <li class="item-child-view"><p>Item3</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps! [Reference](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v3.0.0-pre.5/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#tables-using-marionette-3)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution above will render the li element directly under the containing div or other region specified, unless you also specify

```
tagName: "ul"
```

Then it renders the li elements within a ul element within the specified region.